# can we use a smps to light a 15w bulb?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, stepper-motor

i am making a motorized slider(nema 23 stepper motor), where i have also included a power supply of(12V 20A SMPS - 240W) i also need to include a 15watt bulb in it, is there anyway to do it or do i have to completely use another connection and switch to connect that bulb.THANKS

Comment: It's totally not clear what you have and to what you want to connect that bulb. This question is inanswerable without a schematic.

Comment: 240W - one NEMA 23 stepper generally ought to leave more than 15W for a bulb. So there's likely a way to do it.

Comment: You could get a 12V light bulb and then connect it to the 12v power supply.

Comment: What are your bulb specs? Is it rated to work on DC or AC voltages? What is the rated voltage?

Answer (score 0):

- A 15W tungsten bulb draws 150W on warm-up.
- 15W LED bulbs do not have this problem and are much brighter unless rated in equivalent power.
- NEMA 23 is just a 2.3×2.3 inch (58.4×58.5 mm) faceplate.

  - This does not define the length which affects the current rating and your power consumption P=V*I per 2 windings.(max) although 4.2A is pretty common for the long 2LxW ones.
  - thus 8.2Ax12V=100W per motor or 200W total
  - leaving 40W to spare if it is an LED bulb only.

[image]

You may need thermal design changes to reduce temp rise in the motors such as reduced current on hold or micro-stepping with less torque.

- I suggest a same size  1 W muffin fan if you are using 100W all the time with full steps, running at half speed as the air velocity is what counts.

### Additional info

- I highly recommend **GRBL Panel** over windows to a CNC shield on an Uno with uploaded flash using Gcode sender.
- then optimize the parameters for optimal max acceleration, velocity to suit your mass, torque and seek times without skipping from 0 to 1m in 1s with 0.x mm resolution